# In which source file should I define a function

Tags: c++, function, optimization

Recently I've noticed that in a project where I have several source files (`file1.cpp`, `file2.cpp`, ...) it may affect to execution time wether function A, that will be called by another function B, is defined in the same source file than that function B or not.

In my case, when both are defined in the same `file1.cpp`, function B takes about 90% of execution time, and profiler analysis does not return execution time for function A (called by B).

BUT if they are defined in separated files, then execution times increases in ~150% and function A takes ~65% of time, while B is just ~25 (about 90% in total).

Why has execution time increased? Has function defitinion location an effect on how are they called? I can't figure out.

I should say at this point that I'm using optimization level 3 so function A should be inlined in B in both cases.

EDIT: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 14.04, anf I compile with `g++` and the following flags: `-O3 -pg -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11`.

I include also A and B son it can be better understood. As you can she, A is called from B by another C function, but that one seems to not be a problem:

A:

```
size_t A (const Matrix& P, size_t ID) {
  size_t j(0);
  while (P[j][0]!=ID) {
    ++j;
  }
  return j;
}
```

B:

```
Matrix B (const Matrix& P, const Matrix& O, Matrix* pREL, double d, const Vector& f) {`

  size_t length (O.size())      ;
  Matrix oREL ( *pREL ) ;

  for (size_t i(0); i<length; ++i) {
  for (size_t j(0); j<=i; ++j) {
    double fi(f[O[i][0]-1]);
    if (f.size()==1) fi = 0.0;
    if (i!=j)  {
        double gAC, gAD, gBC, gBD, fj(f[O[j][0]-1]);
        if (f.size()==1) fj = 0.0;
        gAC = C(pREL,P,O,i,j,dcol,dcol);
        gAD = C(pREL,P,O,i,j,dcol,scol);
        gBC = C(pREL,P,O,i,j,scol,dcol);
        gBD = C(pREL,P,O,i,j,scol,scol);
        oREL[i][j] = 0.25 * (gAC + gAD + gBC + gBD) 
                          * (1 - d*(fi+fj));                        
    } else if (i==j) oREL[i][i] = 0.5 * ( 1.0+C(pREL,P,O,i,i,dcol,scol) ) 
                                      * (1.0-2.0*d*fi );           
    }
 }

  delete pREL;

  return oREL;
}
```

C:

```
coefficient C (Matrix * pREL, const Matrix& P, const Matrix& O, 
                    size_t coord1, size_t coord2, unsigned p1, unsigned p2) {
double g;
size_t i, j  ;
i = A(P,O[coord1][p1]);
j = A(P,O[coord2][p2]);
if (i<=j) g = (*pREL)[j][i];
if (i>j ) g = (*pREL)[i][j];

return g;
}
```

Comment: Might be due to inlining. Without whole program optimization you only get inlining of those function calls where the function definition is known in the call's translation unit.

Comment: What compiler and operating system and computer are you using? What optimization flags are you giving? Show some source code related to the issue (e.g. the function A and the function B) Please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The compiler can only inline a function when it knows the function definition at the point of inlining. It may not know it if you place it in other compilation unit. In your case I'd assume that the compiler is "thinking": he's calling this function but I don't know where it is yet, so I make a normal call and let the linker worry about it later.

For that reason code that should be inlined is very often placed in header files.

Comment: Writting the function A in the header file of the source code containing B (`B.h`) solves the problem as writting it in `B.cpp` does. Why should we prefer writting it in the header file? By the way, maybe I'm missing something, but just writting `inline` in front of function declaration does not solve the problem. In fact the program does not compile. In any case, this comment was very helpfull, thank you!

Comment: First of all, `inline` is just a hint for the compiler. Nothing more. A hint may be ignored and certainly will be be ignored if the compiler is not able to inline code. The compiler will certainly not inline code that is available only at linking stage.

Second, I don't say you should prefer putting implementation in header files in general, but in specific cases. In particular when you have template methods or when you expect some code to be always inlined for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you care about performance and benchmarking, you should enable [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) in your compiler.

I assume you are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux so you compile with `g++`.

You should compile with `g++ -Wall -O2` if you care about performance.

You could enable [link time optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) by compiling *and linking* with `g++ -Wall -O2 -flto`

Of course you could use `-O3` instead of `-O2`